# Magento 2: Product image to be displayed one by one instead of slider

Tags: magento2, product, layout, configurable-product

Right now the images are shown in slider but I want to show them one by one 
like

> 1st image
>
> 2nd image
>
> 3rd Image

Not like the slider

[image: Current]

```
Gallery.phtml
```

***contain the following code***

```
<div class="product-image-popup" style="width:<?= /* @noEscape */ $_width ?>px;">
<div class="buttons-set"><a href="#" class="button" role="close-window"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Close Window')) ?></span></a></div>
<?php if ($block->getPreviousImageUrl() || $block->getNextImageUrl()) :?>
    <div class="nav">
        <?php if ($_prevUrl = $block->getPreviousImageUrl()) :?>
            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_prevUrl) ?>" class="prev">&laquo; <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Prev')) ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($_nextUrl = $block->getNextImageUrl()) :?>
            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_nextUrl) ?>" class="next"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Next')) ?> &raquo;</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($_imageTitle = $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentImage()->getLabel())) :?>
    <h1 class="image-label"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_imageTitle ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$imageUrl = $block->getImageUrl();
?>
<img src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($imageUrl) ?>"
    <?php if ($_width) :?>
        width="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_width ?>"
    <?php endif; ?>
     alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCurrentImage()->getLabel()) ?>"
     title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCurrentImage()->getLabel()) ?>"
     id="product-gallery-image"
     class="image"
     data-mage-init='{"catalogGallery":{}}'/>
<div class="buttons-set"><a href="#" class="button" role="close-window"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Close Window')) ?></span></a></div>
<?php if ($block->getPreviousImageUrl() || $block->getNextImageUrl()) :?>
    <div class="nav">
        <?php if ($_prevUrl = $block->getPreviousImageUrl()) :?>
            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_prevUrl) ?>" class="prev">&laquo; <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Prev')) ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($_nextUrl = $block->getNextImageUrl()) :?>
            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_nextUrl) ?>" class="next"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Next')) ?> &raquo;</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to display vertically small images?

Comment: yes I want them to be vertically align..

Answer (score 2):

Go to the the file **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/etc/view.xml**

see a **variable navdir.**

change the thumbnails alignment in Fotorama.

default set as:

```
<var name="navdir"> horizontal</var>
```

Change the code like this:

```
<var name="navdir"> vertical</var>
```

to make the thumbnails as vertical.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">
         <!-- for product page thumbnail -->
         <var name="gallery">
            <var name="navdir">vertical</var>
         </var>

    </vars>
</view>
```

Image Look like
[image]

Comment: Actually I don't want the slider and also don't want the images to be displayed at the side I want to be displayed One by one under this big image with same size

Answer (score 0):

Please override below file and remove other code and add below code:
File Path: app/design/frontend/Yourtheme/Yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

```
<?php
$galleryImages = $this->getGalleryImages();
$_product = $this->getProduct();
?>
<div class="gallery-images">
<ul class="small-image" style="list-style: none;padding: 0;">
<?php foreach ($galleryImages as $image): ?>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" class="product-more-image">
    <img style="width: auto;" class="lazyload" data-src="<?= $image->getData('small_image_url')?>" src="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl('images/loader.gif')?>" alt="<?= $_product->getName() ?>" />
  </a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="main-image-container">
<ul class="main-image" style="list-style: none;">
    <?php foreach ($galleryImages as $image): ?>
      <li><a href="javascript:;" class="product-image"><img style="width: auto;" class="lazyload" data-src="<?= $image->getData('medium_image_url')?>" src="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl('images/loader.gif')?>" alt="<?= $_product->getName() ?>" />
      </a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```